# Upgrade from 14.04 specifically to 16.04.3, not 16.04.4

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I see that do-release-upgrade tells me that it will upgrade to 16.04.4.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -c  
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu  
Checking for a new Ubuntu release  
New release '16.04.4 LTS' available.  
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

Help tells me there is no way to specify version to upgrade. It just does whatever is latest out there.

My usecase needs to be able to upgrade to that specific version from 14.04. How may I upgrade specifically to 16.04.3 instead of 16.04.4 ?

Comment: 16.04.3 is EOF - end of life. You need to upgrade or install 16.04.1. See this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack You may be able to install 16.04.1 and change kernels, but do not understand need for 16.04.3?

Comment: Its a requirement I got and can't argue with. But the question in general is more about is there no way of upgrading to a specific version of MY choice rather than what the latest stable release is?

Comment: What software do you use which works on 16.04.3 and will not work (will work incorrectly) on 16.04.5? If it is kernel - you can always stay on 4.4 as it was on 16.04.0.

Comment: I have no idea what deps might break. The point is, is there a way to upgrade to a specific version that I want? It seems unreasonable to me that I can't choose.